# How to extract numbers from string

Tags: r

I have a string of the form

```
myString <- "[-7254.6525:1.0468013108342776E-19;-1612.1450000000002:1.2422203331775682E-15;-5642.5075:2.8679731025539593E-18]"
```

This string contains a list of pairs of numbers. Each pair of numbers is seperated by a ":" and each pair is seperated by a ";"

I want to extract the numbers and put them into a vector or matrix like this

`-7254.6525             1.0468013108342776E-19
-1612.1450000000002     1.2422203331775682E-15
-5642.5075              2.8679731025539593E-18`

I'm trying to avoid loops. This is what I have so far

```
strsplit( gsub ("\\[|\\]", "", myString ), split=";" )
```

but I'm not sure what to do after this without getting messy and inefficient. Any bright ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way:

```
nrow <- length(gregexpr(";", myString)[[1]])+1
numbers <- as.numeric(strsplit(substr(myString, 2, nchar(myString)-1), ";|:")[[1]])
mat <- matrix(numbers, nrow=nrow, byrow=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant way, but it does the job

```
t(matrix(unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(gsub ("\\[|\\]", "", myString ), ";" )), ":")), 2, 3))

     [,1]                  [,2]                    
[1,] "-7254.6525"          "1.0468013108342776E-19"
[2,] "-1612.1450000000002" "1.2422203331775682E-15"
[3,] "-5642.5075"          "2.8679731025539593E-18"
```